# Joomla Security REST API OAuth

Tags: api, security, rest, joomla, oauth

I am in the early stages of planning (in particular for the security) of a REST API through which a mobile application authenticates and then sends data to be stored in (and also to be retrieved from) the Joomla website/database. It's basically an application-to-application authentication.

I plan to use the API for own internal use which means that the otherwise important aspect of "making it easy for third party developers/API users" is not as important. My main concern is that I of course want to prevent that illicit information can be injected through such API calls. At some stage I might also be asked by external auditors about how this security aspect is properly covered - hence I better be prepared from the start... ;)

SSL is planned to be used for client/server communication and the API will also use a username/pw for authentication, But does anyone have an opinion about (and maybe experience with) using OAuth as a security layer? I do not mean using user's social media pw for the Joomla login, I mean implementing oAuth on the Joomla Component side (i.e. the Joomla side REST API).

Thanks

Comment: There is currently a pull request in the Joomla CMS Github repository for an Auth1 server class. You might want to take a look at that since it will make your life easier and is already well tested.  PS If you think it's good to have, please make a comment on the issue discussion.

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what we have done at our organization. It would have been nice to follow some existing OAuth (I assume OAuth 2) implementation using Joomla but I don't think it exists other than vanilla php implementation. We used this active [project](https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php) but built our own from scratch. This project takes into account all Grants and I suspect if you are doing mobile app authentication like us you will stick to the `Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant`. So it really depends on what you are doing.

So the first part was authenticating with Joomla from our mobile app. Here is a [post](http://www.camcloud.com/blog/joomla-component-tutorial-login-authentication-from-an-external-app) on the start of that. With that we followed the spec [RF6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) to follow the convention needed and produced the proper `Bearer Token` etc.

Then it was a simple matter of doing what was needed for the mobile apps with the REST APIs.

I'm over simplifying it (especially since I'm recommending going through the RFC carefully) but once you know how to authenticate with Joomla, your sailing. IMO.

Comment: The only thing I would say is that OAuth1 is an established standard and OAuth2 remains in process so I would probably do OAuth1

Comment: IMO OAuth2 fits better with mobile applications as it added Flows to allow better support for non-browser based applications. This started in 2006 and finally published Oct. 2012. It replaces OAuth1. Much debate for OAuth2 but it would be a hack to go with the old OAuth1 spec that didn't even consider mobile apps since it is so old. Adapting it is possible and @Elin is right as it is more established. I just don't think for long.